# Conditional Route immediately executes inside Switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Switch with a series of Route elements in my main container:

AppContainer.js

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`/app/:slug/`}>
    <Redirect to={`/app/${slug}/home`} />
  </Route>
  <ProtectedRoute
    path='/app/:slug/userAdmin/'
    component={UserAdminContainer}
    message={'This page is read-only'}
  />
  [snip]
  <Route
    path='/app/:slug/protectedRoute/'
    render={(props) => (
      <ReadOnlyError message={props.message} />
    )}
  />
</Switch>
```

Along with the `ProtectedRoute.js`

```
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  const { message } = props;
  const { isReadOnlyUser } = useUser();
    
  return (
    isReadOnlyUser
      ?
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/app/:slug/protectedRoute/',
            state: {message}
          }}
        />
      : <Route {...props} />
  )
}
```

And the `useUser` function

```
function useUser() {
  const context = React.useContext(UserContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`User data is not provided to this component`);
  }

  return context;
}
```

My problem is that when `AppContainer` renders, it is then immediately redirected to the `ProtectedRoute` of `"/admin"`, when it should only render if that button was hit. I'm a longtime Java dev, brand new to React. I'm sure there's something about the rendering process I'm not understanding.

Comment: Where is a `"/admin"` route rendered? Can you clarify in better detail what exactly the issue is? What are any reproduction steps?

Comment: The actual path is "/app/:slug/userAdmin/". It's a container in `AppContainer`, but the URL changes to the `ProtectedRoute` immediately after loading the page. It's immediately executing the `Redirect` that gets returned.

Comment: I guess the `isReadOnlyUser` value is falsey. Can you [edit] to include this `useUser` hook and (*presumably a context provider*) code as part of a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: I think I understand. Yes, `isReadOnlyUser` is evaluated several times as the page renders. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What typically happens is that the initial "auth" condition incorrectly matches either the ***confirmed*** authenticated or unauthenticated states. In other words, it's not simply a binary decision, but that there are actually 3 options: "confirmed authenticated", "confirmed unauthenticated", and "we don't know yet". Unless you are able to directly determine and initialize the `isReadyOnlyUser` state into one of the "confirmed" cases, you'll want to initialize to the "unknown" case using a value that neither indicates a user is authenticated nor unauthenticated, and then explicitly check this condition and conditionally return early ***and not*** render the protected content or redirect until auth status is confirmed.

Example, a "confirmed" `isReadOnlyUser` is a boolean `true|false` value, so a great "unknown" initial value would be `undefined`.

```js
const [isReadyOnlyUser, setIsReadyOnlyUser] = useState(); // undefined

useEffect(() => {
  // check user is read-only on app/component mounting
  // update isReadOnlyUser
}, []);

...

return (
  <UserContext value={{ isReadyOnlyUser, /* ...other context values ... */}}>
    {children}
  </UserContext>
);
```

```
import { Route, Redirect, useParams, generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ message, ...props }) => {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const { isReadOnlyUser } = useUser();

  if (isReadyOnlyUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }
    
  return isReadOnlyUser
    ? (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: generatePath("/app/:slug/protectedRoute/", { slug }),
          state: { message }
        }}
      />
    ) : <Route {...props} />
}
```

Comment: For some reason I don't see my comment where I thanked you for this great answer. This solved my problem, thanks!!

Comment: @CNDyson Some types of comments get auto-flagged as "noise" and auto-deleted based on key words. Users can also manually flag comments as "It's no longer needed. This comment is outdated, conversational, or not relevant to this post." I appreciate the sentiment though. Either way, votes and answer acceptances are usually good indicators of thanks and appreciations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the user isn't loaded on the first render. This might happen if you need any server (or third party) communication for your user to load. With this assumption, one solution would be to wait until the user is loaded. Effectively, you'd probably want to separate the following scenarios:

- The user is currently being loaded
- The user is logged out (or credentials expired, loading was unsuccessful)
- The user was loaded successfully

If you prevent hitting the switch until the user is loaded, it should work.